# Xcode 11.5 showing incorrect thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, swift5, xcode11

Recently I migrated my current codebase from Swift 4.2 (Xcode-10.3) to Swift 5 (Xcode-11.5).

While testing I put a breakpoint on **tableView** **Datasource** and found that current (Xcode-11.5) showing background thread on the breakpoint. As there is no possibility to run UIKit on background thread this is alarming for me. see the attachments

[image: table view datasource]
[image]

> Use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread or main dispatch queue, unless otherwise indicated. This restriction particularly applies to classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

1. How to fix this issue?
2. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You must add some more information as where and how the view controller and the table view are being initialized.

Are you programmatically setting the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the table view? If so, try that inside `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` block.

If that is not the case, check if it is the main thread inside `cellForRow` using DispatchQueue's `isMainThread` property. And check where you initialize the tableView.

In other case, the whole View Controller may be called inside a background thread. Check for that also.

Comment: UI doesn't update on the background thread. Tableview is updating perfectly but Xcode showing background thread.

Comment: @AlizainPrasla As from the name of the thread, I assume it's customarily created. Check the declaration and check whether the `.reloadData()` is called inside that thread. And if it were actually a background queue, you'd get errors while updating UI elements. It'll crash and the errors would be highlighted with purple.

Comment: on cell for row delegate, I add a breakpoint and check with `po Thread.isMainThread`.
it returns true

https://ibb.co/7KPZG08

Comment: Yes. That means the thread is actually a Main Thread but the "label" of the Thread is that "..background..". It may be declared like `let aThread = DisPatchQueue(label: "background.thread", qos: .default)` where default is Main Thread. So, when you do `aThread.async {...}`, it actually picks up the Main Thread.